# SQL get friends from friends table by username

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

Ok, I'm stuck with table design which I'm not able to change now and I need based on username to get all his friends from friends_relationship table

What I have now:

```
select distinct(username) from members m
inner join members_friends f on f.id_memb_friend1 = m.id
where (f.id_memb_friend1 = 173 or f.id_memb_friend2 = 173)
```

members table has columns: id, username
member_friends table has columns, id, id_memb_friend1, id_memb_friend2

The query I posted will return also username of member with id 173 who is the owner and his nickname for example is Splendid.
What I want to achive is to get all the friends together with username, based on username which I provide (Splendid = id 173).

Update:

I want to achive this:

Input: username=Splendid
Action: get usernames of splendid friends (together with their ids)
Output:

members.id = 5
username = John

members.id = 15
username = Lara

members.id = 66
username = Alex

and so on...

Comment: Your questions is slightly confusing. Can you post what sample output would look like and what table each column needs to come from?

Comment: I provided the output... thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated to accommodate the new requirement expressed in comments.)
(Updated to accommodate the new requirement expressed in the updated question.)

Your question is (was) inconsistent about whether you want to search based on username or user id.  Although your query uses id, I use the username per the clarified requirement.  I'm also supposing that you want the *friends*' usernames (only).  Additionally, it appears from your initial query that you want to look at relationships in both directions (match on friend1, display all friend2, AND match on friend2, display all friend1).

Here's one way to do all that:

```
select mm.id, mm.username
    from members mm
    inner join member_friends f on f.id_memb_friend1 = mm.id
    inner join members m on m.id = f.id_memb_friend2 
    where m.username = 'Splendid'
union distinct
select mm.id, mm.username
    from members mm
    inner join member_friends f on f.id_memb_friend2 = mm.id
    inner join members m on m.id = f.id_memb_friend1
    where m.username = 'Splendid'
```

Comment: Ok, then you need to join the members table a second time.  Answer updated.

Comment: Updated again to also provide the friend's ID, as described in the updated question.

Comment: All good, only u are missing = at second inner joins. Thanks, will test it lil bit more, and then accept it!

Comment: Oops.  Added the missing = signs.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CASE f.id_memb_friend1 WHEN '173' THEN f.id_memb_friend2 ELSE f.id_memb_friend1 END AS `MemberID`, m.`username` FROM members_friends f inner join members m on f.id_memb_friend1 = m.id OR f.id_memb_friend2 = m.id
where (f.id_memb_friend1 = 173 or f.id_memb_friend2 = 173)